# Apex replace \" in string

Tags: apex, json, escape, replaceall, replace

```
String jsonString = 'Error \"fatal\"';
String jsonString2 = jsonString.replaceAll('\\"', '');
System.assertEquals(jsonString, 'Error fatal', 'Assertion failed');
```

The jsonString variable comes from a callout.

The code above fails to remove \" from the jsonString. Am I encoding the backslash the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.assertEquals(jsonString, 'Error fatal', 'Assertion failed');
```

Should be:

```
System.assertEquals('Error fatal', jsonString2, 'Assertion failed');
```

Because strings are immutable (cannot be changed), so all string manipulation methods return a new string. Also, notice I changed the parameters around for the assert so it reads correctly. The expected value goes before the actual value.

Also, you don't to escape `"` in Apex source code, because it's not a reserved character, unlike most programming languages.

However, you do need to escape `\\`. Further, using String.replaceAll means you want to use a regular expression. Regular expressions also need to be escaped, so your source ends up being `\\\\`:

```
String jsonString = 'Error \\"fatal\\"';
String jsonString2 = jsonString.replaceAll('\\\\"', '');
System.assertEquals('Error fatal', jsonString2, 'Assertion failed');
```

Comment: you are altering jsonString. jsonString is a string we get from an external API callout. It comes as 'Error \"fatal\"' with a single backslash

Comment: @dev4life I agree. But my point is that in Apex (as in this sample code), you must escape the string to make it comparable with the JSON you're receiving. Now, if you're using replaceAll, you need four literal backslashes to make two backslashes for the regular expression to match one literal backslash in the string.